# How to test wcf in real environment

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I had made a service using wcf i tested it by making a project to a client of type asp.net and it works perfect.I hosted the service and the client on the IIS i wanted to run  without opening the visual studio.when i closed the visual studio and put my URL of the client project it gives me this error

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find
>   default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 27:  Line 28:                 System.IO.FileInfo fileinfo = new
>   System.IO.FileInfo(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName); Line 29:
>   ServiceReference1.IService1 clientupload = new
>   ServiceReference1.Service1Client(); Line 30:
>   ServiceReference1.RemoteFileInfo uploadRequestInfo = new
>   ServiceReference1.RemoteFileInfo(); Line 31:                 Link =
>   FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
>
> Source File: C:\Users\KHALED\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WcfServicefiles\WebApplication2\Default.aspx.cs    Line:
>   29
>   **here's the web.config of the service**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
  executionTimeout="14400"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServicefinal.Service1"   >
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Service1"
                  contract="WcfServicefinal.IService1" >

        </endpoint>
      </service>

    </services>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Here it is the web.config of the client**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/WcfServicefinal/Service1.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: yes i can navigate to the service without running VS

Comment: I have added the web.config of the service and the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a good idea to try hosting your service in a console app as a first go. Sean is right, it would be helpful to see your configuration.

When running your service in visual studio, the service is automatically hosted for you. When testing outside visual studio: Run your service host, open a browser and enter the BASE address of your host. You should see a page with a link to the wsdl definition if meata data is available.

A base address may look like http://192.168.89.73:8080/base  with the IP address of your machine, port number....

Answer (score 0):

[WCFTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) shipped with VS is for testing the WCF.